# Есть ли какие-либо ограничения при построении http запросов в yandex-tank-е?

Tags: яндекс-танк

При тесте танком, вижу одни ошибки `71 Protocol error`, curl на подобных запросах получает 200 Ok. 
Есть ли какие-либо ограничения при построении http запросов в yandex-tank-е?

конфиг танка:

```
tester@tank:~/test$ cat load.ini 
[phantom]
rps_schedule=line(1,10,10)
address = ...
[monitoring]
config=none
tester@tank:~/test$
```

Кусок консольного вывода танка:

```
NET for 5 RPS:                
5 100.00%: 71 Protocol error
```

В логе phout-а все http коды ответов нулевые, есть только 71е ошибки (формат лога нашел в [этой доке](http://phantom-doc-ru.readthedocs.org/en/latest/analyzing_result_data.html#phout-txt)):

```
tester@tank:~/test$ cat logs/757372/phout_efwfw9.log | awk '{print $11, $12}' | uniq -c
55 71 0
tester@tank:~/test$
```

в логе фантома есть записи `413 Entity too big`

```
tester@tank:~/test$ head logs/757372/phantom_COS85f.log 
2015-12-04 17:28:42.279 +0300 [info] [] Start
2015-12-04 17:28:42.281 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 055] format error
2015-12-04 17:28:42.529 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 001] 413 Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:42.529 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 001] Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:43.273 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 007] 413 Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:43.273 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 007] Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:43.794 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 008] 413 Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:43.794 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 008] Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:44.223 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 006] 413 Entity too big
2015-12-04 17:28:44.223 +0300 [error] [benchmark_io 006] Entity too big
tester@tank:~/test$
```

Запрос curl-ом возвращает 200:

```
tester@tank:~/test$ curl -v  http://...  > /dev/null 
...
> GET ... HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: ...
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:38:59 GMT
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Length: 16141533
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=60
< Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Nov 2015 13:14:21 GMT
< 
{ [data not shown]
100 15.3M  100 15.3M    0     0  23.7M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23.8M
* Connection #0 to host ... left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
r2d2@t34:~/test$
```

Answer (score 3):

Судя по выводу curl-а, размер запрашиваемого ресурса больше дефолтных 8 Мбайт.

Попробуйте выставить в конфиге танка в секции `[phantom]` большее значение, например

```
phantom_http_entity = 30M
```

Также стоит обратить внимание на следующий кусок [документации](https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#phantom-http-module-tuning-options):

> phantom_http_line - First line length. Default - 1K
>
> phantom_http_field_num - Headers amount. Default - 128
>
> phantom_http_field - Header size. Default - 8K
>
> phantom_http_entity - Answer size. Default - 8M.
>   Please, keep in mind, especially if your service has large answers, that phantom doesn’t read more than defined in phantom_http_entity.